# Java Cli CommandLineParser

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use Java cli commanlineparser to parse the follwing arguments,

```
java -OC:\mydirectory -NMyfile
```

Option -O is for directory and -N is for the name of file.

I have been looking online but couldnt find a good example and this is what I am trying to do,

```
Option option = new Option()
option.addOpton("O",true, "output directory)
option.addOpton("N",true, "file name)
...
CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
...
if (cmd.hasOption("O")
...
```

Basically, I am trying to add multiple options and be able to parse them.  Is this correct way to run the program with above options?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried it? Is there a problem? Are you using the apache commons cli library or are you trying to implement it yourself?

Comment: Yes and I am using apache cli.  I am getting "UnreconginziedOptionExcepton"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
...
Option opt1 = OptionBuilder.hasArgs(1).withArgName("output directory")
    .withDescription("This is the output directory").isRequired(true)
    .withLongOpt("output").create("O");

Option opt2 = OptionBuilder.hasArgs(1).withArgName("file name")
    .withDescription("This is the file name").isRequired(true)
    .withLongOpt("name").create("N")

Options o = new Options();
o.addOption(opt1);
o.addOption(opt2);
CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();

try {
  CommandLine line = parser.parse(o, args); // args are the arguments passed to the  the application via the main method
  if (line.hasOption("output") {
     //do something
  } else if(line.hasOption("name") {
     // do something else
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

*Also, you should leave a blank space between the argument and the value in the command line.*